# Show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 + x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 + x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$. I'm thinking about using an ismorphism theorem.

Define $\phi:\mathbb{C}[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ by $\phi(x) = t^3$ and $\phi(y) = -t^2$.

First, does this map define a homomorphism of rings? If so can someone elaborate how I can prove that.

Second, how can i show that $\ker \phi = (y^2 + x^3)$ and that Im $\phi = \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably want $\phi(x) =-t^2$ and $\phi(y) = t^3$ since otherwise we don't have $\phi(x^3+y^2)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The question originally asked to show that ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(y^2 + x^3)$ and ${\mathbb C}[t]$ were isomorphic)

These rings are not isomorphic: ${\mathbb C}[t]$ is a unique factorization domain, but ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(y^2 + x^3)$ is not, because $y^2 = -x^3$ in that ring.

Your reasoning breaks down at the last step: $t$ is not in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 + x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$?

Comment: Yes, using exactly your argument. Note that this also shows that the field of fractions of ${\mathbb C}[x,y]/(y^2,x^3)$ is isomorphic to ${\mathbb C}(t)$; maybe this is what you were thinking of.

Comment: I believe so, so what I am trying to prove is $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 + x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}(t)$.

Comment: It's $Q({\mathbb C}[x,y]/(y^2+x^3)) \cong {\mathbb C}(t)$.

Comment: Gotcha. So lets say I want to prove that $\mathbb{C}[x,y] / (y^2 + x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$. Is my defined $\phi$ correct?

Comment: Actually, no, because $y^2 + x^3$ is not in the kernel of your $\phi$. You have the exponents wrong, but the idea is ok.

Comment: What should my $\phi$ be?

Comment: Should $\phi(x) = t^2$ and $\phi(y) = -t^3$.?

Comment: Nearly; $y^2 + x^3$ is still not in the kernel of $\phi$. It needs a small change.

Comment: How about $\phi(x) = -t^2$ and $\phi(y) = t^3$

Comment: Yes, indeed, that one works; I thought that was the one you had in mind from the start anyway.

Comment: I did I was just getting confused.